# Dynamic Content Inside a List in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I want to render a list of **A** `Cardview`s and inside each `CardView`, I need to have **X** buttons. Here, **A** is a constant (say 30), whereas **X** can be modified by the user (depending on his/her preferences; won't exceed 15 though).

To build this, my first reaction as a newbie was to have a `RecyclerView` inside each item of a `RecyclerView`. While several SO answers try to suggest a way to do this, it looks a bit messy.

Another way I thought of would be to actually place those 30 `CardView`s with different IDs inside my layout file, but managing them would become a huge pain.

I need a way that is cleaner than what I have thought of above. What would be the best way for me to proceed with the above problem?

---

**Edit**

Okay, so idea #3 is to have a `RecyclerView` with `CardViews` having static content, and a fixed bar of buttons at the bottom instead of having it inside every card.
I would prefer a solution to the original problem, but if nothing works out, this is what I'm, going to go ahead with.

Comment: Trying to imagine your logic source, I think the best result would be achieved making each `CardView` an item of a `RecyclerView`. You could bind the views and the functionality to each button, of course. Theoretically, if they are too detached and the constraints are too unique to each, you _could_ make individual fragments, each with its `RecyclerView` and binding logic to the contents inside each card, wrapping all inside one scrollable container. However, for the little I know, you may bump into (mainly inertial) scrolling issues, or, possibly, more serious dimensional ones (measuring).

Comment: @DavidCesarino exactly, apart from the fact that I will need to handle each click inside each `CardView` separately (whilst the functionality remains the same), the scrolling would be a huge issue, especially on low-end devices. The only workaround I can think of right now is to modify my UI so that I have a fixed footer with buttons at the bottom and a `RecyclerView` with `CardViews` having static content, though I would still prefer a solution to the initial problem statement.

Comment: Can't you delegate the clicking logic through the holders and adapter to a handling class? You set the clicking in the viewholder and pass some kind of unique ID, which is something you would be doing anyway. I think that would be the best first try, generally. If/when you have some code, then we could approach an answer.

Comment: When I click on the view in the viewholder, I'll need to know which element of the viewholder the click was on. But since the viewholder has a dynamic number of elements, I'm not sure what I'd do.

Comment: When binding the holder, you find the container layout view, create the buttons and add them to the container view. At this moment, you're able to individualize each button, so you can either create your `OnClickListener`s _or_ set some kind of id to your buttons (I'd probably try `setTag` first) so that this individual identification can be accessed when the listener's `onClick` is called (the behavior complexity will answer if individual listeners are needed). The most important detail is (probably) tying button to fragment/activity, but the adapter is exactly the place for that crossing.

Comment: @DavidCesarino sounds right, I'll give it a try and see if I face any hurdle specific to my application.

Comment: I have another doubt. Isn't adding buttons programatically to each of the views a very heavy operation?

Comment: Certainly, and there will be a lot of measuring going on, but I refrained from talking about that because it is a different question/issue altogether, related to the architectural decisions of your program, and the profiling should be up to you. If that is a hindrance, you could rethink your UI/workflow as to not present everything at once in the face of the user. Break the selection into smaller steps

Comment: @DavidCesarino that's what I am going to do now. I am going forward with idea#3 (in the question) for the time being.